# how to detect browser size using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, mobile

I have a Wordpress header.php page which looks like this...

```
<?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) : ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="logo"
width="206" height="136" border="0" class="logo" />

<?php else : ?>

<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo_inner.png"
alt="logo" width="187" height="130" border="0" class="logo" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

so when the current page is not the home page a different logo is used.

I want to know if it is possible to add some code in the 'if' section to detect the browser size because I want to use a different logo on mobile. I know you can do this using Jquery e.g.

```
if ((screen.width<=420)) {
 //do something
}
else {
//do something else
}
```

and I've tried using Detect Mobile script -  http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ hoping to replace the logo but the php code overrides the jQuery code.

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile==true){ 
   jQuery('.logo').attr('src','.../images/mobile_logo.png');
} else { 
   jQuery('.logo').attr('src','../images/logo.png'); }
```

Comment: Why not using Media Queries?

Comment: PHP runs on the server **before** the page is sent to the browser, so there is no way in hell you'd be able to figure out what size the browser is **before** the page is even sent to the browser.

Comment: oh yes. why didn't I think of that. Thanks I will give that a go

Comment: @adeneo is right. In theory, the browser could include screen size info in its request, but it doesn't. And in any case, since this is a presentation concern, CSS is the right place to address it. After all, the user could load your page, then resize their browser afterwards. If you handle this with CSS, the browser can adjust on the fly.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a problem you should address server-side.  This is a CSS issue.  Include something like the following in your stylesheet(s):

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) {
  /* mobile styles here */
}
```

Check [this article](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) for more information on media queries.

Comment: Why not, webrouwser identifier strings are send to server upon http connection, servers could based on that serve different pages.
without overhead of client side determination of what that client is.
server side might work faster. unless its a stressed server already.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is use a different logo, the css approach is probably good enough.

However, if you'd like to use PHP (or Java or .NET) to learn about the nature of the device at the server, so as to serve different markup (or js or css files) to different devices, then you may want to take a look at WURFL, the Wireless Universal Resource File.  I've been playing around with it a little.  I don't think it gets the screen sizes or orientations right, but it can definitely identify the devices I have (iPhone, nexus7, and kindle):

[WURFL at Sourceforge.net](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/wurfl.php)

Comment: wurfl isnt php based its not server side detection

Answer (score 1):

If you would like the best of both worlds you can use WURFL with Javascript to show and hide the image.

Here is an example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//wurfl.io/wurfl.js"></script>

if(WURFL.is_mobile){
    jQuery('.logo').attr('src','.../images/mobile_logo.png');
} else {
    jQuery('.logo').attr('src','../images/logo.png');
}
```

This is a cloud service offered by ScientiaMobile (WURFL) that is doing server side detection and returning a JSON object with the device information.  If you want, more of their documentation is available at http://wurfl.io/.

If it is only the size of the image that you are worried about, you could also use their image resizer, which will resize the image to best suite the device that is loading it (depending on how you configure it).

Answer (score 0):

why not make the php generate a small logo/placeholder and then use javascript to load a bigger version depending on your browser size. You could even use something like lazyload for jQuery (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). You can make it as advanced as you like, like adding a resize detection so people don't have to reload the page when they resize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function CurrentWidth() {
        $CurrentWidth = "<script> var mobilewidth = screen.width; if(mobilewidth < 1400){ document.write('smallDesktop'); }else{ document.write('largeDesktop'); } </script>";
        echo $CurrentWidth;
    }

// Please place CurrentWidth() function into your functions.php
//You can use your custom width instead of 1400
// Usage: echo CurrentWidth() return your value
// If you want find height, Please use screen.height;
// you received typeof as string(133) value, It's not working So please use above script in js. and make hide show class according to your condition.
```

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery it might work like this:

```
$(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 599) {
        // change your image.
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. "using php" 2. There are much better approaches. This one would cause the image to change during the page load, which would both look odd and cause extra HTTP requests and bandwidth usage.

Comment: It is not possible with php! This was fresh in my mind from a project today. I felt it was relevant to share.

Comment: I know it's not possible with PHP. If you're going to propose a solution here, you should at least note that (and that you're using a technically non-standard library, jQuery) in your answer. It's also a poor solution compared to media queries.

Comment: I thought that would have been obvious seeing as JQuery  was referenced in the question as an attempted solution.

Comment: Take nothing for granted on SO young Skywalker. Explain all of your actions so that they may be understood by all.